# React-Native ImageBackground repeat not working

Tags: react-native, repeat, imagebackground

I started to learn react-native and I encountered a problem.
I need an image to repeat in the background but it's streched.
It seems the resizeMode is not working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  home: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'repeat',
    backgroundColor: '#882829'
  }
});

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/stain_pattern.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <View style={styles.home}>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            <Button
              title="Go to Details"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
            />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'repeat'}}. Refer documentation [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image-style-props)

You need apply  repeat in image style

```
<ImageBackground
  source={require('../assets/stain_pattern.png')}
  style={styles.backgroundImage}
  imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'repeat' }}
>
  <View style={styles.home}>
    <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    <Button
      title="Go to Details"
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
    />
  </View>
</ImageBackground>;
```